# PHP jQuery HTML - Getting custom HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a PHP file which puts out all orders in the system and adds the custom attribute `oid` (order-id) to all the links. My links look like:

```
<a href='#' class='completeOrder' oid='$order_id'>$status</a>
```

Which gives correct html, when I do inspect element I get this

```
<a href='#' class='completeOrder' oid='8'>Un-completed</a>
```

What I would like to do is when this link is clicked, spawn a form with checkboxes and a submit button with the correct order ID in it's html to send. So I can send the form and the order id to another PHP file for processing ( in this case updating the order status ).

What I am doing to spawn the form with the checkboxes is using a jQuery AJAX call, but when I try to alert the order ID to check if jQuery got the oid correctly it tells me its undefined... :

```
$("body").delegate(".completeOrder", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getCompleteOrderTools();

    $(".content").toggleClass("hidden");
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(800).removeClass('hidden');
    $("#notifications-drop").toggleClass('hidden');
});

function getCompleteOrderTools() {
    var o_id = $(this).attr('oid');
    alert(o_id);

    $.ajax({
        url:   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            getCompleteOrderTools: 1,
            orderId: o_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".row").append(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: your jquery version ???

Comment: Note that custom attributes in your HTML are invalid. If you want to store custom metadata in an element, use a `data-*` attribute instead. Also `delegate` was deprecated a *long* time ago. You should update your version of jQuery and use `on()` instead

Comment: Really? Because in the products part I was able to set pid = product_id.. and use the same technique and it worked?

Comment: It may work as HTML is very forgiving (some would say too much), but it's not valid.

Comment: Im using this jQuery version

Comment: set "oid" in a hidden input!

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: I could use onclick, but I my content is loaded by ajax calls, so I have to use delegate, else onclick doesnt work

Comment: To solve your problem, `this` within `getCompleteOrderTools()` will not be the element you clicked on as it's called under a different scope. You would need to provide the element as a parameter to the function.

Comment: $(this) is not defined in getCompleteOrderTools

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that solved it, ty!

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue was that you are referencing `this` in wrong context as the `this` available in your function `getCompleteOrderTools` is different that `this` that you wanted to refer for the click event of your desired link.

You have 2 options :

either use `jQuery(this).attr('oid');`

Or

use jquery `data` attributes

`<a href='#' class='completeOrder' data-oid='$order_id'>$status</a>`

`jQuery(this).data('oid');`

So your code with `.attr` will look like :

```
$("body").delegate(".completeOrder", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var myThis = $(this);//This is the 'this' corresponding to the link clicked

    getCompleteOrderTools(myThis);

    $(".content").toggleClass("hidden");
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(800).removeClass('hidden');
    $("#notifications-drop").toggleClass('hidden');
});

function getCompleteOrderTools(myThis) {

    var o_id = myThis.attr('oid');
    alert(o_id);

    $.ajax({
        url:   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            getCompleteOrderTools: 1,
            orderId: o_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".row").append(data);
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery object ain't passed to your function. You should do the following:

```
$("body").delegate(".completeOrder", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    getCompleteOrderTools(jQuery(this));

    $(".content").toggleClass("hidden");
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(800).removeClass('hidden');
    $("#notifications-drop").toggleClass('hidden');
});

function getCompleteOrderTools(_this) {
    var o_id = _this.attr('oid');
    alert(o_id);

    $.ajax({
        url:   "action.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            getCompleteOrderTools: 1,
            orderId: o_id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $(".row").append(data);
        },
    });
}
```

By passing `jQuery(this)` to your function, you now have full access to the jQuery object from your click event.